# Compiling issue in Dlib for face detection

Tags: c++, image-processing, compiler-errors, dlib

I am new to try dlib library. I have gone through the compiling instruction but still the problem persists.
I am using command line for compiling and execution.
I used the following commands and gave me errors.

```
g++ -O3 -I.. ../dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 face_detection_ex.cpp -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/423Kc.png)

Thank You

Comment: Did you link the static libs?

Comment: @DimChtz  there is no instruction for linking static libs. Can u elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link to libjpeg.  The instructions here http://dlib.net/compile.html tell you what to type to make g++ link to libjpeg.  Which is -ljpeg.